# clear the old values from textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am looking for a way to clear the old values from textbox when I refresh the page using javascript.

I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById("FIRST").value = "";
    document.getElementById("END").value = "";
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're doing? Web pages are stateless. They don't "remember" their old values unless you've implemented a way for it to do that (e.g. you're using and posting to a server technology that does so). Also, can you show **all** of your code? Just the JS code snippet doesn't help much.

Comment: either your id's are wrong, or you are trying to set a value for an element that doesn't have a visible value like checkbox/radio

Answer (score -2, accepted):

consider executing your javascript inside the $(document).ready function

Comment: He hasnt tagged this with jQuery tag, nor is he showing use of jQuery in his code.

Comment: @PatrickEvans if you took a look at his profile you would see that he is using jquery, and even if he wasnt, then maybe he should have been??? lol

Comment: shouldn't have to look at peoples profiles to get information that should be in the question